# Upgrading Joomla 1.5 site to 2.5 using jUpgrade unique article alias issue

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to upgrade my Joomla 1.5.26 site to Joomla 2.5 using jUpgrade 2.5. During the update process jUpgrade gets stuck on `Migrating undefined`.

After enabling the debug, the error shown is

```
JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_ARTICLE_UNIQUE_ALIAS
```

Is there a way to prevent this unique article alias error?

Screenshot below

[image]

Comment: You have articled with the same alias , can't you just manually change them in database before upgrading your joomla?

Comment: I used sp Upgrade and was able to do the migration.

Comment: Good to know you did it, so please write an answer to your question for others to use.

Comment: @Faridv : I did not solve the "undefined undefined" issue for jUpgrade. I simply tried a different (paid) component SPUpgrade. So that will not count as an answer to the question.

Comment: That's OK, I thought maybe it can be helpful for other users.